# Firebase opposite of toObject or create a method that returns a map for an object

Tags: java, android, firebase, hashmap, pojo

I have a pojo class in my android app and I'm using firebase to store them, I can retrieve them from firebase using toObject

```
DatabaseUser user = documentSnapshot.toObject(DatabaseUser.class);
```

but I wondered if there is an equivalent for saving them to firebase as currently I have to do something like this

```
        Map<String, Object> user = new HashMap<>();
        DatabaseUser userObject = params[0];
        user.put(Constants.FS_NAME, userObject.getUser_name());
        user.put(Constants.FS_STATUS, userObject.getUser_status());
        user.put(Constants.FS_NUMBER, userObject.getUser_number());
        user.put(Constants.FS_IMAGE, userObject.getUser_image());
        user.put(Constants.FS_BLOCKED, userObject.getBlocked());
        user.put(Constants.FS_SMALL_IMAGE, userObject.getUser_image());
        user.put(Constants.FS_RECENT_MSG, 
        userObject.getUser_recent_message());
        user.put(Constants.FS_MSG_TIME_STAMP, 
        userObject.getMsg_time_stamp());
        user.put(Constants.FS_TIME_STAMP, userObject.getUser_time_stamp());
        user.put(Constants.FS_ID,userObject.getUser_id());
```

I couldn't find anything in the docs to help and I'm not an expert in Java, I tried making a method in my pojo class that returned a map like this this:

in my DatabaseUser class

```
 public Map toMap(DatabaseUser userObject){
    Map<String, Object> user = new HashMap<>();
    user.put(Constants.FS_NAME, userObject.getUser_name());
    user.put(Constants.FS_STATUS, userObject.getUser_status());
    user.put(Constants.FS_NUMBER, userObject.getUser_number());
    user.put(Constants.FS_IMAGE, userObject.getUser_image());
    user.put(Constants.FS_BLOCKED, userObject.getBlocked());
    user.put(Constants.FS_SMALL_IMAGE, userObject.getUser_image());
    user.put(Constants.FS_RECENT_MSG, userObject.getUser_recent_message());
    user.put(Constants.FS_MSG_TIME_STAMP, userObject.getMsg_time_stamp());
    user.put(Constants.FS_TIME_STAMP, userObject.getUser_time_stamp());
    user.put(Constants.FS_ID,userObject.getUser_id());
    return user;
}
```

but it requires me to make a new database user each time to call toMap on it can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong or suggest a better way

Comment: What you're doing is pretty typical.

Comment: Yeh I know  but it's sooo ugly! And as I have 4 classes all going from objects to maps it's becoming hard to ignore, any ideas of a decent toMap method

Comment: oh i changed the returned map from Map to Map<String, Object> and the errors regarding unchecked assignments went away think this will work now many thanks